# Is it possible to get a longer "expires_in" for the Implicit Grant Flow?

Tags: spotify

Related: is there a best practice for refreshing an Implicit Grant Flow token without requiring the user to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the [Implicit Grant Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow). You must use the [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) so you can refresh the token and only requires the user to login once. The down side is you need a backend server handling this for security.